# How to set column type when the column has both numerics and excel functions?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm querying data from another excel file and 2 of the columns - PRICE and FEES - have numeric values in some rows (e.g. 1, 0.8 etc.) and excel functions in other rows. The functions reference other columns in the same table to get the number result.

Currently I have this in the power query:

```
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"PRICE", type **any**}, {"FEES", type **any**}})
```

But it displays the cells which have functions as text instead of 'general' and don't show the result of the function without manually clicking into the cell and hitting Enter. The format in the excel of the columns is already 'General'.

I'd like to see the number result of the functions straight out after refreshing the query without having to manually update the cells.

I tried to change the 'type' in the query to number, but then the cells with functions come out empty:

```
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"PRICE", type **number**}, {"FEES", type **number**}})
```

I also tried in 'Table' >> 'External Data Properties' to tick & untick "Preserve cell formatting" but both settings give the same result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Kindly edit your question after reading the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In the Power Query editor, are the formulas displayed as formula text? The only way I could reproduce this was to format the ***source workbook*** as text. Does your source workbook also display the formula text?

[image]

If this is the case, Power Query will load the data into the worksheet table as text, no matter how the worksheet is formatted. There is no other way you can format the text in Power Query. And you will have update the cells after loading, either by editing and pressing enter, or pressing F2, or by macro.

If there are only a few formulas, you could also add a step to replace the formula text with a Power Query formula:

```
 #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Table1_Table,"=[@PRICE]*0.1",each [PRICE]*0.1,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"FEES"})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the format in the source file is indeed Text. I think your suggestion to replace the formula text with a Power Query formula could work.
But I'm getting a 'Token comma expected' error on the first "Then" word in the below and can't figure out where I went wrong:

Comment: #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","=IF([@[Index]]<=15,0.8,IF([@[Index]]<=25,0.82,IF([@[Index]]<=50,0.85,0.87)))", each If [Index]<=15 Then "0.8" Else if [Index]<=25 Then "0.82" Else if [Index]<=50 Then "0.85" Else "0.87",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Price"})

Comment: Try like this `= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type", each [Fees], each if [Fees] = "=IF([@[Index]]<=15,0.8,IF([@[Index]]<=25,0.82,IF([@[Index]]<=50,0.85,0.87)))" then (each if [Index] <= 15 then "0.8" else if [Index] <= 25 then "0.82" else if [Index] <= 50 then "0.85" else "0.87") else [Fees],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Fees"})`

Comment: = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type", each [Fees], each if [Fees] = "=IF([@[Index]]<=15,0.8,IF([@[Index]]<=25,0.82,IF([@[Index ]<=50,0.85,0.87)))" then (each if [Index]<=15 then "0.8" else if [Index]<=25 then "0.82" else if [Index]<=50 then "0.85" else "0.87") else [Fees],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Fees"})           It does something but instead of returning the value result, it returns this text: [Function] in the cells where the formulas were.

Comment: Try removing an `each` like so: `= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type", each [Fees], each if [Fees] = "=IF([@[Index]]<=15,0.8,IF([@[Index]]<=25,0.82,IF([@[Index]]<=50,0.85,0.87)))" then (if [Index]<=15 then "0.8" else if [Index]<=25 then "0.82" else if [Index]<=50 then "0.85" else "0.87") else [Fees],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Fees"})`

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. It's still not working. Maybe because I didn't have the [Index] column in the query, it's added as excel function to the table outside the query. The function to pull the [Index] from another table is based on "index name" (column headers of the other table) and "date" (row 'headers'). It's an INDEX(MATCH,MATCH) formula and I can't figure out how to translate that into power query. Don;t want to create separate tables for each "index name" because there are too many.

Answer (score 0):

Is the column using the same formula for all the rows, but some were just formatted as text?  If so, after converting them all to general, select all the cells then tab until you reach one that is displayed as formula.  F2, then **CTRL+ENTER**.  This will all highlighted cells with the same formula.

You could also filter for rows that have a formula so that you only CTRL+ENTER fill the formula on those selected/filtered cells.